# getting slotProps from nested slot

Tags: vuejs3

I have a dynamic table. Table and table columns are separated components. And I am using columns as slot in table components.

**main file**

```html
    <DynamicTable :contents="contents">
      // columns finding and displaying data from props dynamically. it works without a problem
      <Col th="name" td="name"/>
      <Col th="information" td="information"/>

      // here I am giving custom slot inside last column, but button not displaying additionally I can't reach the content data via slotProps //
      <Col>
        <template #content="slotProps">
          <button @click="getData(slotProps.content)">click me</button>
        </template>
      </Col>
    </DynamicTable>
```

**dynamicTable** component

```html
    <slot></slot>

    <div v-for="content in contents" :key="content.id">
       <div v-for="(td, idx) in body" :key="idx">
          // if there is slot given as template render <slot>
          <slot v-if="td.children" name="content" :content=content></slot>
          // else render dynamic value
          <span v-else>{{ content[td.name] }}</span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

```js
    const slots = useSlots() ? useSlots().default : null;
    const body = ref([])
    
    slots().forEach(slot => {
      body.value.push({
        children: slot.children,
        name: slot.props?.td,
      })
    })
```

additionally **Col** template

```html
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        th: {
          type: String,
          default: null
        },
        td: {
          type: String,
          default: null
        },
      },
      render(){
        return null
      }
    }
    </script>
```

In a situation like above, how can I display button element inside given `<Col>` component as slot and getting the :content="content" data as `slotProps`.

And if you need to know, content Array looks like below.

```js
    const contents = ref([
      {
        id: 341,
        order_id: 1,
        name: "susan",
        information: "inf context",
      },
      {
        id: 453,
        order_id: 2,
        name: "jack",
        information: "info context",
      }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

You're trying to access `slotProps` in Col component,
But the Col component is not passing any props.

The required data is available in `DynamicTable` component
And you're already passing it to the slot of `DynamicTable`

1. You can access the `slotProps` as below

```
    //App.vue
    <DynamicTable :contents="contents" v-slot="slotProps">
        <Col th="name" td="name" />
        <Col>
            Access slotProps directly, no need to use template
            {{slotProps.content}}
        </Col>
    </DynamicTable>
```

2. And you need to remove slot name

```
    //DynamicTable.vue
    <slot v-if="td.children" :content="content"></slot>
```

3. Also refactor the `Col` component

```
    //Col.vue    
    /* remove render function */
    ...
    <template>
       <slot />
    </template>
```

### Solution

You can find a working demo below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-cntmmb?file=src/App.vue

Comment: thank you for the answer. but there is one big problem. If I give two custom slot, column repeats itself with the customs. for example; https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-9frvj6?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Fixed it. Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gkude1?file=src/App.vue

Comment: But to be honest, the way you have implemented DynamicTable to iterate over slots in order to render each column is not an efficient method as it send unnecessary data for each column

Comment: thank you, i am open to another solution if there is one. I am actually trying to imitate this; https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/datatable/dynamiccolumns